# Unity2D Rigidbody2D.AddForce

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто осведомлен в особенностях работы метода `Rigidbody2D.AddForce`.

Есть точка `Vector2 point` с заданными координатами. Есть объект - мячик - который должен лететь в данную точку со своей позиции и при достижении ее продолжить свободный полет.

При выполнении такого метода на объекте

```
public void Push() 
    {   
     GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(point * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);   
    }
```

Мячик летит не по направлению к заданной точке, а в совершенно другую строну.

Я новичок в Unity, возможно использую метод неправильно или вообще этот метод не подходит для такой задачи?

Comment: Поставь куда-нибудь минус и полетит в другую сторону

Comment: Так дело не в самом направлении, скажем точка от объекта справа, он и летит вправо, но куда то в другую точку, не в заданную. Если поставить минус - полетит в неправильную сторону совсем.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вектор направления силы у вас задается вектором координат объекта. А нужно как вектор направления силы использовать разницу векторов положения объекта и цели (т.е. вектор, направленный из объекта в точку цели), поделить на его длину (чтобы получить вектор единичной длины) и умножить на значение силы.

Comment: insolor, здоровья вам! детей богатых.

Comment: insolor спасибо, проблема решена, все летит куда надо

Answer (score 0):

```
// запрет на множественный компонент у одного объекта
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
// обязательное наличие компонента, добавляется автоматически, если отсутствует
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    // что бы поля внутренней кухни (приватные) были видимы в инспекторе и сохраняли значение используется SerializeField
    [SerializeField] private float _power = 10f;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Rigidbody2D _body;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // GetComponent и transform затратные команды, поэтому ссылки на них нужно кашировать
        _transform = transform;
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Push (Transform target)
    {
        // вектор от шара до цели
        Vector3 Power = target.position-_transform.position;
        // вектор с длинной 1 помноженный на силу
        Power = Power.normalized*_power;
        _body.AddForce(Power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```